# React/Redux - How to access form input errors from within component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a redux form that shows errors when the input doesn't validate, which is all fine and dandy, but I'm trying to create a global "Please fill in the required fields" down by the submit button when a user goes to submit, as a way to let the user know "oh hey, I need to scroll back up and find something that wasn't filled out".

My connect function looks like this:

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'requestForm',
    validate,
})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RequestForm));
```

Where `validate` is a separate js file that looks like:

```
function validate(formProps) {
    const errors = {};

            if (!formProps.get('account_name')) {
                errors.account_name = 'Required';
            }
            if (!formProps.get('street')) {
                errors.street = 'Required';
            }
            if (!formProps.get('city')) {
                errors.city = 'Required';
            }
            if (!formProps.get('state')) {
                errors.state = 'Required';
            }
            if (!formProps.get('zip')) {
                errors.zip = 'Required';
            }
            if (!formProps.get('contact_name')) {
                errors.contact_name = 'Required';
            }
            if (!formProps.get('contact_phone')) {
                errors.contact_phone = 'Required';
            }

    return errors;
}

export default validate;
```

In my component, is there a way I can access that `errors` property and determine the total number of errors on submit?

Answer (score 0):

So when using Redux Form, you have access to a number of props via `this.props`, so all I did was add a snippet of HTML like so:

```
 {!this.props.valid && !this.props.pristine &&
    <p style={{color:"#f44336", fontSize: "12px", marginTop: "10px"}}>*Please fill in all required fields</p>
}
```

All I'm doing is checking the `pristine` and `valid` properties of `this.props` and it works great!